# How do I get the x word of a line in command prompt?

Tags: grep, command, prompt

At the moment I got:

```
tasklist | grep java
```

Which delivers the following line:

```
java.exe      1234 Console     1      100.0k
```

Now I just need the second parameter, in this case 1234.

```
tasklist | grep java | ???
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
tasklist | awk '/java/{ print $2 }'
```

Comment: Thank you, but when I enter this, it says command 'awk' not found or is wrong spelled.

Comment: What platform are you on that does not have `awk` available?

Comment: Windows 7, maybe an environment var is not set, im looking it up atm, gawk exists too apparently, but cannot find that either on my system...

Answer (score 1):

Use `awk` to print the 2nd word for lines that match your grep pattern

```
tasklist | grep java | awk '{print $2}'
```